# DiscordJS - Fetch Multiple Users at Once

Tags: discord, discord.js

Instead if fetching every user by itself, I am trying to fetch an array of users at once.

This is the code I am trying to use:

```js
var idsArr= ['682999909523259483','234269235071811584','503303866016727050'];
  
    
const membersArr = await interaction.guild.members.fetch({
    idsArr,
});
    
console.log(membersArr);
```

Even though I only give it an array of 3 IDs, it logs every member of the server.
Any suggestion on how to fix that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just searched through official discord.js examples, and found this:

```js
// Fetch by an array of users including their presences
guild.members.fetch({ user: ['66564597481480192', '191615925336670208'], withPresences: true })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.error);
```

Maybe you should do this instead:

```js
var idsArr= ['682999909523259483','234269235071811584','503303866016727050'];
  
    
const membersArr = await interaction.guild.members.fetch({
    user: idsArr,
});
    
console.log(membersArr);
```

(Notice field name `user` instead of `idsArr`)